# Происхождение слова "мул"

Tags: этимология

Мул — помесь осла и кобылы. Но совершенно не понятно, почему он так называется. С "лошаком" все ясно: смесь слов "лошадь" и "ишак". А откуда взялся "мул"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По всей видимости, этимология слова *мул* восходит к латинскому "mulus", с таким же значением, а вот как конкретно слово оказалось в русском обиходе непонятно.

Заимствование сравнительно недавнее, и в древнерусском данного животного называли мъскъ или мьскъ (по Фасмеру). Скорей всего, непосредственно в русский язык, слово попало  через украинцев, а те в свою очередь, переняли его у поляков.

Comment: Какие "мулы" через украинцев? В русском немало заимствований из польского или через польский, но это всегда происходило напрямую, Польша(большая ее часть) была в составе России, поляки - российскими поддаными, были времена, когда все польское было в моде в России, но малороссийское наречие в те времена было бесписьменным, какого-то серьезного влияния на общерусский литературный язык(язык образованного, сведущего населения) оказать не могло. На мой взгляд, просто этот термин МУЛ естественным образом заменил слово МЪСКЪ, в результате некоторой европеизации культуры на Руси в 16-17 веках

Comment: @Варяг-91 вы описываете ситуацию второй половины XVIII - XIX вв., а основные заимствования от поляков были в XVII в. Культурное влияние польского в этот период времени было огромным. Причем было два периода наиболее активного заимствования: Смутное время и присоединение левобережной Украины. Слово "мул" появилось в русском языке как раз во второй период. И захолустьем называть не стоит,  Никонианский раскол произошел как раз от того, что обряды русских земель стали приводить в соответствие с обрядами присоединенных территорий, где уровень образования на тот момент был выше, чем в России.

Comment: @ Марк Из Ваше замечание совершенно справедливо, но не было при Речи Посполитой никакого образования на украинском языке, как и самого языка и "украинцев" в современном понимании этого слова. Употребляя "на Руси" я, конечно же, имел в виду всю Русь, и ту, что была под поляками, ранее под Литвой. Если разные русские местные наречия принимать как языки, то можем признать и вологодский язык, и вятский, и т.д. Киев(точнее - Лавра), был общепризнанным русским религиозно-культурным центром, хотя были и иные.О всплеске культуры в России в 17 веке  http://sunapse.ru/rushistory/Culture/culture4.html

Comment: @Варяг-91, я в ответе  говорил не об украинском языке, его ещё не было, а об украинцах, через  которых польское слово проникло в русский язык. Как некая общность, протоэтнос украинцы к XVII веку уже образовались.

Answer (score 0):

На иври МСХ смешивать. Что соответствует древнерусскому. В латыни возможно от корня мултус- как качество нечистоты породы (множественный смешанный).
Иври МСХ  ведет к лат. микстуре- смесь.микст.